# More efficient alternative for ifelse loop in R

Tags: r, if-statement

For creating a new variable based on another variable (class = factor), I made an `ifelse` loop.

The data:

```
eu <- data.frame(structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 12L, 9L, 13L, 16L, 18L, 27L, 10L, 25L, 21L, 28L, 19L, 8L, 26L, 6L, 3L, 15L, 14L, 11L, 17L, 20L, 23L, 24L, 2L, 22L, 7L), .Label = c("Belgie", "Bulgarije", "Cyprus", "Denemarken", "Duitsland", "Estland", "Europese Unie", "Finland", "Frankrijk", "Griekenland", "Hongarije", "Ierland", "Italie", "Letland", "Litouwen", "Luxemburg", "Malta", "Nederland", "Oostenrijk", "Polen", "Portugal", "Roemenie", "Slovenie", "Slowakije", "Spanje", "Tsjechie", "Verenigd Koninkrijk", "Zweden"), class = "factor"))
names(eu) <- "land"
```

My `ifelse` loop:

```
eu$plicht <- ifelse(eu$land=="Belgie", "ja",
                    ifelse(eu$land=="Italie","ja",
                           ifelse(eu$land=="Cyprus","ja",
                                  ifelse(eu$land=="Griekenland","ja",
                                         ifelse(eu$land=="Luxemburg","ja",
                                                ifelse(eu$land=="Spanje","ja","nee"))))))
```

However, I'm wondering if there a more efficient way of doing this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
eu$plicht <- ifelse(eu$land %in% c("Belgie", "Italie", "Cyprus", "Griekenland", "Luxemburg", "Spanje"),
                    "ja", "nee")
```

Comment: (@Jaap , too:) If it's only about a binary variable, a similar approach could be `c("nee", "ja")[eu$land %in% c("Belgie", "Italie", "Cyprus", "Griekenland", "Luxemburg", "Spanje") + 1]`. It seems to be faster too: `x = sample(letters, 1e5, T); identical(ifelse(x %in% letters[1:10], "ja", "nee"), c("nee", "ja")[x %in% letters[1:10] + 1]); microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ifelse(x %in% letters[1:10], "ja", "nee"), c("nee", "ja")[x %in% letters[1:10] + 1], times = 10)`